# Biometrics: Displaying error message if face recognition is considered weak

Tags: androidx, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

An app I came across shows the following error "**This app doesn't support face recognition for verifying your identity. Use your fingerprint sensor instead**" when tried to use Biometric face recognition when face recognition in the device is weak. They are not using [BiometricManager.Authenticators](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricManager.Authenticators) to determine if biometric is STRONG or WEAK. Is there any other way that is possible to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Authenticate the biometric prompt with the crypto object and the biometric prompt will show the following error if only unsecured biometrics are present.